.po файлы как забрать metadata
Проект на django мультиязычный.
Появилась необходимость проверять даты обновления переводов. В документации написано, что .po файлы содержат небольшое количество мета данных.
Вопрос: как забирать даты последних обновлений?
Понятное дело, что можно открыть файл, прочитать, забрать и закрыть. Но я не хочу внутри проекта обращаться к файловой системе. Должны же быть какие то методы для извлечения таких данных в django
UPD
Дочитал доку по django.utils.translation и вот некоторый вывод: скорей всего такого метода нет, поскольку используются скомпилированные .mo файлы для поддержки мультиязычности
Но вопрос остается, как на клиенте через API проверять появление обновления для переводов. Код не нужен, просто описание.

Что значит «на клиенте через API»?

@andreymal react native приложение, которое забирает переводы через API (drf)

Переводы приложения react native должны быть в репозитории приложения react native, зачем тут django вообще

@andreymal реализовано без собирания и публикацию приложения в маркетах. Не большое количество переменных с переводом хранится в AsyncStorage, забираются переводы через DRF запросы. То есть добавление перевода проходит как добавить сущность языка в настройки, собрать po, скомпилировать mo. И в приложении появляется новый язык

Вы в любом случае делаете что-то странное, перевод приложения относится к приложению а не к API

@andreymal да я не спорю что это так. API это возможность получить данные переводов. drf поддерживает мультиязычноть

@andreymal я бы почитал за "странность". Мне не кажется такая организация процесса чем то странным. А вот публиковать обновление к приложению каждый раз, когда появляется новый язык, так себе занятие

Мультиязычность django и drf предназначена для перевода сообщений бэкенда, а не сообщений приложения. А для перевода приложения абсолютно все просто выпускают новую версию приложения и не парятся

@andreymal хорошо. Чуть поглубже. Приложение обслуживает ПЛС машины, у каждой машины собирается конфигурация, которая содержит лейблы и сообщения для регистров, которые пересылаются по modbus. Так вот, при добавлении новой конфигурации обновлять приложение не получится, поскольку все сущности должны быть переведены. Таких конфигурации порядка сотни, машин порядка 10к. И клиентов на разных языках подрядка 30

Для парсинга po файлов можно библиотеку babel использовать. Открываете файл через read_po: https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/messages/pofile.html, потом метаданные смотрите в полученном объекте через свойство mime_headers: https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/messages/catalog.html#babel.messages.catalog.Catalog.mime_headers. А так po формат - текстовый. Если только дату обновления нужно вытащить можно просто руками парсить ее, просто регуляркой, например.


Это все при условии, что дата обновления перевода там есть. Откройте файл текстовым редактором, посмотрите в самом начале, есть ли она.


А, ну это естественно противоречит условию "Но я не хочу внутри проекта обращаться к файловой системе". Но по-другому никак, сам django действительно берет текст из бинарного файла mo, а в нем никаких метаданных нет.

@insolor вчера пересмотрел подход. Наличие даты в po файле не является гарантией обновления перевода. Пока не скомпилирован mo, данные из po  не имеют значения. Следовательно, при компиляции перевода надо отлавливать и сохранять в базу, а из базы забирать время последнего обновления.

Ну, чисто технически можно дату создания mo файла в файловой системе смотреть

Да, серверным скриптом. Или в докере команду compilemessage расширить

Не верная логика - использовать данные из po файлов для проверки обновления переводов. Данные которые содержат эти файлы не являются подтверждением того, что перевод скомпилирован и применен к проекту.
Выход, это отслеживать дату изменения mo файла/ов, который обновляется после вызова команды
python3 manage.py compilemessages

Здесь может быть разный подход как проверять последнюю дату mo файла. Мне больше по душе это кастомизировать compilemessages. Примерно так
class Command(CompileMessagesCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # здесь вызываем оригинальную команду compilemessages
        super().handle(*args, **options)

        # здесь пишем логику для добавления даты обновления прямо в БД, например

и хранить дату изменение прямо в бд.
Критику привествую

Теперь compilemessages оказывается намертво привязана к продакшеновой БД, плюс ещё одна странность в дополнение к кучке всех предыдущих странностей

@andreymal ну так скажите как надо.
